# Why don't I have a Network Manager?

Tags: 17.10, network-manager, internet

I recently built a PC and then installed Ubuntu 17.10 onto it with a USB. When I went to connect to a wifi, there was no Network manager tool, so how do I enable it? I really want to know how to turn it on so that I can do stuff on it. Thanks in advance. `lsusb`

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu? Did you try System Settings --> WiFi?

Comment: Latest Ubuntu release use `netplan` instead of Network Manager

Comment: I have 17.10 release of Ubuntu.

Also when I type netplan into Terminal, it says
'usage: netplan [-h] [--debug] …
netplan: error: You need to specify a command

Comment: Oh also if I go to wifi it says "oops, something has goen wrong. Please contact your software vendor."
"NetworkManager needs to be running"

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I don't think this is true for the desktop edition

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 What do you want me to edit? Also I put that in terminal and it says

'0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no'

Comment: Do you have a PCI or a USB wireless device?

Comment: @Pilot6 I do have a USB for wifi but when I plugged it in nothing happened.

Comment: Then [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` command.

Comment: Typing `lsub` is not what I asked for.

Comment: Typing `lsusb` is not better ))))))) I am trying to find out what is your wireless device. LOL I am leaving.

Comment: @Pilot6 Sorry I thought you meant in question. I typed lsusb  in Terminal and it came up with a few things.

Comment: So you can do "a few things" to fix your problem ;-)

Comment: What do you mean @Pilot6?

Comment: I'm going to be gone so I won't be able to answer anything till the 22.

Comment: I am home now if anybody wants to help me still. I also ran `nm-applet` and it just said it wasn't running